# jQuery add index to URL string in hidden input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, url

I'd like to add the index of a given radio button to a URL string, but in the middle and have that passed to the value of a hidden input in a form.

here is the code so far:

## jQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('input[name="Names"]').click(function () {
var idx = $(this).index(':radio')
$('.submission input[name="image"]').val("http://URL/images/0 + (idx + 1) + .jpg");
})
});//]]>  
</script>
```

## HTML

```
<div class="submission">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="I'm Here Notification Sign" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="http://URL/images/01.jpg"/>
</div>
```

This obviously doesn't work, but for output i'd like to see `http://URL/images/02.jpg` when clicking on radio button 2 etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What obviously doesn't work about it?

Comment: What rjreed said! Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nz7Qz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line needs to be:

```
$('.submission input[name="image"]').val("URL/images/0" + (idx + 1) + ".jpg");
```

You were passing one big string literal instead of concatenating them like you meant to.

Comment: Also, you may need to coerce idx to a number to get it to add instead of concatenating: (+idx + 1)

Comment: yep, that's it...just had the syntax wrong :-)  Thanks guys!